# Who is this person?

Tags: art, identification

I came across with the following picture, which is a little blurry and unclear. Unfortunately I couldn't find anything about it. Can anybody help me ?

[image]

Comment: No help from Google image search - I'm pretty sure it isn't [Peter Cushing](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5a/Grand_Moff_Tarkin.png).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

John Everett Millais, "Self Portrait" - 1880, Uffizi Gallery Florence

[image]

[John Everett Millais](http://www.wikiart.org/en/john-everett-millais/self-portrait)

Comment: +1. Is it ok to ask how you identified it?